# Carcassonne- bridge to abbey tile?

Tags: carcassonne, expansions

With Carcassonne, can I place a bridge on a field that ends on an abbey tile used to fill up a hole (see [link](https://wikicarpedia.com/index.php/Abbey_and_the_Mayor#/media/File%3AAbbey_And_Mayor_C2_Feature_Abbey_Tile.png) ) without any bridge on the abbey tile ( which shouldn’t be there anyway)?
The tile can be used to fit a hole and closes everything (roads, cities etc.) But I am not sure if this works the other way around. Normally you cannot put any tile next to this one, since the condition is that all neighboring tiles are already there before you can place this abbey tile. Is it then valid to place a bridge on a neighboring tile, so that the bridge will end up at the special abbey tile?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the rules for the expansion "Bridges, Castles And Bazarrs" [here](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/f4/bc/f4bc7284-0193-4abe-b0c9-0706b8ebf34f/carcassonne_exp8_rules.pdf) it says: -

> You can place one bridge on the tile you just placed, or on a tile
> touching the tile you just placed. When placing a bridge, you must
> place both ends in a field, and it must be placed facing either
> left-to-right or up-to-down (it cannot be placed diagonally across the
> tile). Once placed, a bridge remains on that tile until the end of the
> game.
>
> You can place a tile so that a road ends against a field, but you must
> place a bridge that continues the road on that same turn. You can use
> multiple bridges in a row along the same road, but each tile can have
> a maximum of only one bridge on it. Bridges can be placed on tiles
> with meeples on them.

There is no restriction given based on type of tile, ie no restriction is given against building on a cloister/abbey provided it's not breaking any rules above.

On page two of the rules an example is given which explicitly uses a cloister tile.  Again showing there is no restriction against this.  Again provided you are not breaking any other the other rules stated above.

[image: Example from rules which uses a cloister tile.]

If you look at the rules for Abbeys which are [here](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/48/90/48909233-453b-446f-bbb6-3aee9058a41b/zm7815_carcassonne_exp5_rules.pdf) they say

> The abbey completes the side of each tile directly adjacent to it.

So If a bridge were places leading into the Abbey it would count as the end of the road, completing it that side.   There is nothing in the bridge expansion to say this isn't allowed.   There is nothing in the Abbey expansion to suggest this wouldn't be OK.

Comment: Thank you. But I mean, what if there is an abbey tile (see [link](https://wikicarpedia.com/index.php/Abbey_and_the_Mayor#/media/File%3AAbbey_And_Mayor_C2_Feature_Abbey_Tile.png) ) without any bridge on there.. The tile can be used to fit a hole and closes everything (roads, cities etc.) But I am not sure if this works the other way around. Normally you cannot put any tile next to this one, since the condition is that all neighboring tiles are already there before you can place this abbey tile.

Comment: ah so that's from a different expansion!  always good to put all this info in the question

Comment: Ok, I will update my question, thanks for your advice

Comment: edited answer too.

Comment: If I read [Bridges, Castles and Bazaars](https://wikicarpedia.com/index.php/Bridges,_Castles_and_Bazaars) footnote 2, it says: _As with normal roads, each end of the bridge must continue a road segment (or bridge) already in play or must be adjacent to an empty place for a tile. (12/2014)_. That would mean no bridge can be played adjacent to an abbey tile if abbey tile..

Comment: The full annotated rules do not cover this.  https://s3.amazonaws.com/geekdo-files.com/bgg145108?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22S-CAR_v7.4.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJYFNCT7FKCE4O6TA%2F20221212%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221212T145615Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=120&X-Amz-Signature=e0c516da4d1d35825f36b0b67b0a1d64063e7b14146f37bf9a156c73d6a1ebe4

It's a great question. Maybe contact the publisher if not happy with my answer?